# Adding React-Native to a React project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I currently have a React based website. I want to start on the process of converting the website to also work natively through react-native. I understand that I will need to re-build the UI for the native version.

My goal however is to leave both versions in the same node project so I dont have to update my non-view based code separately for both versions of the code base.

Is it possible to add the dependencies and files necessary for react native while not having to separate the native code out into it's own completely separate project and if so how?

Comment: I think you can re-use most of the backend code. You might have to add new APIs and code for mobile specific stuff...

Answer (score 0):

[Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) is a tool that optimizes the workflow around managing multi-package repositories with git and npm.

Comment: Using [example](https://github.com/erickjth/react-native-web-monorepo-lerna/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It looks really promising. Do you know of anyone who tried to do this with a react app and a react-native app? Looking at the example you linked to, it is based on using React-Native-Web for the web frontend and we really need to stay with regular react for web (there are certain dependencies we have for parts of the app that we are not sharing with native that only work with react not native).

Comment: [Here post](https://medium.com/habilelabs/react-native-react-web-and-expo-together-in-one-monorepo-5b8f9a0fca00) about something, what are you looking for